# Foreach loop through Java Hashmap in Lua

Tags: java, lua, luajava

So I'm new to Lua and I've got LuaJava running with my Java code, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to run a foreach loop on a hashmap in Lua.

In my java code I have this:

**Java**

```
public class EntityManager {

    public static EntityManager EntityManager = new EntityManager();

    private Map<Integer, Entity> entities = new HashMap<Integer, Entity>();

    public Map<Integer, Entity> entities() {
        return entities;
    }
        ....
}

public class Entity {
    private int id;
    ....
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public EntityManager getManager() {
        return EntityManager.EntityManager;
    }
}
```

Then I've got my lua script and I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through all entities in the hashmap in EntityManager:

**Lua**

```
owner = {} -- I set this to an Java object that is a child of the Entity class
function doSomeStuff()
    for i, e in pairs(owner:getManager():entities()) do
        if (e:getId() ~= owner:getId()) then
            -- Do some stuff here
        end
    end
end
```

I've pretty much got everything I need set up for my functions, etc. to work but I don't know how to go about creating a Lua equivalent of a Java foreach loop, to iterate through my Java hashmap in my Lua script.

Also I'd like to know how I can check the type of an object in Lua to see if it's an instanceof one of my Java classes. For example, in Java if I wanted to see if an object is of an object type I would do the following:

```
Entity e;
....
if (e instanceof EntityTypeA) {
    // e is of Entity type A
} else if (e instanceof EntityTypeB)
    // e is of Entity type B
}
```

Oh, and I'm not entirely sure if the Java object I'm passing into the Lua script is retaining it's Java class type, nor do I know how to go about doing such a thing.

By the way, I'm using [LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/index.html) from Kepler Project.

Thanks.